# Throughput calculation in performance testing

Tags: performance-testing

If there are 10k busses and peak point is 9:30Am to 10:30Am, there will be 2% increase of Vusers every year then what is the throughput after 10 years?

Please help me how to solve this type of questions without using a tool.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The formula would be:

```
10000 * (1.02)^10 = 12190
```

With regards to implementation, 10000 busses (whatever it is) per our is 166 per minute or 2.7 per second which doesn't seem to be a very high load for me. Depending on your load testing tool there are different options on how to simulate it, for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) it will be [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer), for [LoadRunner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoadRunner) there are [Pages per minute / Hits Per Second goals](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.56/help/WebHelp/Content/Controller/c_goal_oriented_scenarios.htm#mt-item-1), etc.